# Can I pass in a list as the weights parameter for random.choices()

Tags: python, random

I am trying to use the random.choices method with two lists: names and values. The values list is the weights.

I am calling the method by doing

```
random.choices(names, weights = values, k = 1)
```

The error I am receiving is

```
ValueError: The number of weights does not match the population
```

Can I not use a list as a parameter for the weights? If I can pass in a list in for the population (names), why can't I pass in a list for the weights?

Comment: as stated by the error message, the lists to be the same length.  e.g. the error is saying something like "you've got more names than weights" or the other way around

Comment: It wasn't. It was trying to read in DataFrame type data. I needed to convert them to lists and then it was fine.

Comment: ah, that's because iterating over a Pandas `DataFrame` gives its columns not rows.  kind of annoying there than the length of a dataframe isn't the same number of items as you'd get back via iterating, but ah well, far too late to change the Pandas API now!  if you passed a column, or an index, it would have worked

Answer (score 0):

Because I was reading in my data using pandas DataFrame functions, I was trying to pass DataFrame type data into random.choices which it did not like. I converted the data to lists and it worked.